# How to push notification to specific logged user. My code is shown below

Tags: python, flask, redis, server-sent-events

I am using event stream in front end. Yield function in back end. Storing client in redis queue. 
I am storing users correctly in redis queue, but I don't know to send push notifications to specific logged user.

My problem is how to push notification to specific logged user.

Front end code:

```
  var source = new EventSource('/stream');
            source.onmessage = function (event) {

                 console.log(event)
            };
```

Back end code:

```
from redis import Redis
redis = Redis()


import time
from datetime import datetime
p = redis.pipeline()
 app.config['ONLINE_LAST_MINUTES'] = 5


def check_updates():
   yield 'data: %s \n\n' % data

@app.route('/stream')
   #@nocache
   def stream():
      return Response(check_updates(),mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet shows how to use `redis` operate user:

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/71/

if you use `flask-login`, it's easy to get `current_user` and return the specify message for him/her by checking all the user's fields in database.